# BottomNavigationView not showing up when used with Drawerlayout

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin and making an app with a left navigation drawer and i want to have a BottomNavigationView with the drawerlayout, but when i run the app only drawer layout shows up, the BottomNavigationView is not showing up. but when i use it without DrawerLayout it works fine. i am attaching my xml code please could you tell me where am i going wrong? In the mainactivity i have refrenced the BottomnavigationBar with FindviewbyId<> and added a navigationItemSelected method to the BottomnavigationBar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar3"
        android:id="@+id/drawerlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Main Layout-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/drawerlayout"
            android:id="@+id/mainlayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
          <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:layout_below="@id/drawerlayout"
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:itemBackground="@color/bottom_navigation"
                app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_state"
                app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_state"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
        </RelativeLayout>

      <!--Left Drawer-->

        <ListView
            android:layout_below="@id/mainlayout2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#003160"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="#003160" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend for the NavigationView to behave as a drawer, then the root View should be `<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>`, instead of `<RelativeLayout>`. For more detail information, you could refer to this [official document](https://blog.xamarin.com/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/) and its [sample](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates/tree/master/Xamarin.Android-Templates/Projects/NavigationDrawerCompat).

Modify your code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

  <!-- The main content view -->
  <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout">
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/black"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
  </RelativeLayout>

  <!--Left Drawer-->
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
      app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUZeF.gif).

Comment: stil nothing happening. i am really confused and stuck on this error

Comment: @KeyurHardas, would you mind share a basic demo to reproduce this problem?